# Python, list of pairs of elements from other lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have a series of lists, call them `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`. Now every list has 5 elements with identical names, say:

```
A: [ 'Cars_A', 'Planes_A', 'Houses_A', 'Bikes_A' ] 
B: [ 'Cars_B', 'Planes_B', 'Houses_B', 'Bikes_B' ]
etc..
```

What I want is a list of lists, of the form:

```
[ ['Cars_A', 'Planes_B'], ['Cars_A', 'Houses_B'], ['Cars_A', 'Bikes_B'], 
  ['Planes_A', 'Cars_B'], ['Planes_A', 'Houses_B'], ['Planes_A', 'Bikes_B'],
  ['Houses_A', 'Cars_B'], ['Houses_A', 'Planes_B'], ['Houses_A', 'Bikes_B'],
  ['Bikes_A', 'Cars_B'], ['Bikes_A', 'Planes_B'], ['Bikes_A', 'Houses_B'] ]
```

As can be seen, the rule for this list is:

- An element cannot be grouped with another element from the same set, for example `['Cars_A', 'Planes_A']` is not allowed.
- An element cannot be grouped with a similar element from a different set, for example `['Cars_A', 'Cars_B']` is not allowed.

My attempt right now is to do nested for loops for all 5 lists, but I want to avoid this if possible. Any ideas?

Comment: changed, they are all lists, sorry about that.

Comment: You said __My attempt right now is to do nested for loops for all 5 lists__. Can you show us?

Comment: How do you define "similar" element? Is it "same text up to the underscore" or sth else?

Comment: Same text up to underscore, yes.

Comment: You say the order inside lists is the same, but are all elements also the same (apart from obvius "_A", "_B" difference)? the example suggests so.

Comment: Yes, elements inside are also the same, they are some matrices I need to use later. Namewise, they are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `itertools.permutations` and `itertools.product` with `filter`:

```
import itertools

l = [['_'.join([i,g])for i in ['cars', 'planes', 'houses', 'bikes']] for g in 'ABCDE']
l    
[['cars_A', 'planes_A', 'houses_A', 'bikes_A'],
 ['cars_B', 'planes_B', 'houses_B', 'bikes_B'],
 ['cars_C', 'planes_C', 'houses_C', 'bikes_C'],
 ['cars_D', 'planes_D', 'houses_D', 'bikes_D'],
 ['cars_E', 'planes_E', 'houses_E', 'bikes_E']]

res = []
for sub in itertools.permutations(l, 2):
    res.extend(list(filter(lambda x: (x[0].split('_')[0]!=x[1].split('_')[0]), itertools.product(*sub))))    
res
[('cars_A', 'planes_B'),
 ('cars_A', 'houses_B'),
 ('cars_A', 'bikes_B'),
 ('planes_A', 'cars_B'),
 ('planes_A', 'houses_B'),
 ('planes_A', 'bikes_B'),
 ('houses_A', 'cars_B'),
 ...
 ('bikes_E', 'cars_D'),
 ('bikes_E', 'planes_D'),
 ('bikes_E', 'houses_D')]
```

Comment: that `lambda` line is quite unpythonic, trying to squeeze a bunch of logic in to one line

Comment: using permutations is nice one

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way using `itertools.combinations`, let's just make all the pairs first and then `filter` afterwards.

```
from itertools import combinations

def filter_(tup):
    x, y = tup
    p1 = x.split('_')
    p2 = y.split('_')
    return (p1[0] != p2[0]) and (p1[1] != p2[1])


list(filter(filter_, combinations([*A, *B], 2)))

[('Cars_A', 'Planes_B'),
 ('Cars_A', 'Houses_B'),
 ('Cars_A', 'Bikes_B'),
 ('Planes_A', 'Cars_B'),
 ('Planes_A', 'Houses_B'),
 ('Planes_A', 'Bikes_B'),
 ('Houses_A', 'Cars_B'),
 ('Houses_A', 'Planes_B'),
 ('Houses_A', 'Bikes_B'),
 ('Bikes_A', 'Cars_B'),
 ('Bikes_A', 'Planes_B'),
 ('Bikes_A', 'Houses_B')]


list(filter(filter_, combinations([*A, *B, *C], 2)))

[('Cars_A', 'Planes_B'),
 ('Cars_A', 'Houses_B'),
 ('Cars_A', 'Bikes_B'),
 ('Cars_A', 'Planes_C'),
 ('Cars_A', 'Houses_C'),
 ('Cars_A', 'Bikes_C'),
 ('Planes_A', 'Cars_B'),
 ('Planes_A', 'Houses_B'),
 ('Planes_A', 'Bikes_B'),
 ('Planes_A', 'Cars_C'),
 ('Planes_A', 'Houses_C'),
 ('Planes_A', 'Bikes_C'),
 ('Houses_A', 'Cars_B'),
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a way to do it without `itertools`, but using a fast data stucture from `collections` module, named `deque`

```
from collections import deque
A=[ 'Cars_A', 'Planes_A', 'Houses_A', 'Bikes_A' ] 
B=[ 'Cars_B', 'Planes_B', 'Houses_B', 'Bikes_B' ]

l=[deque(A),deque(B)]
n = 0
for i in l:
    i.rotate(n)
    n += 1
m = zip(*l)
print(list(m))
```